# ¿ Es posible implementar Angular 2 en asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs-2.0, webforms

Me gustaría saber si es posible ya que la información en la web hace referencia en la mayoría de casos a MVC únicamente.

Comment: si andas iniciando con ASP.net MVC, hace un tiempo hice un workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY y si Razor (el motor de las vistas) deseas aprender, revisar este documento debes https://www.slideshare.net/fredyfx/tutorial-ms-web-matrixv4 que la fuerza os acompañe :D

Comment: Acá tienes un tutorial de la implementación que está muy bueno http://mahedee.net/introduction-to-angularjs-and-bootstrap-in-asp-net-web-form/

Comment: ese es el problema, que ese tutorial es con AngularJS y no con Angular 2 :/

Answer (score 1):

Angular es como `jquery` se puede utilizar en cualquier entorno de desarrollo WEB, vaya es una librería de `javascript` o un `framework`, funciona en todos los navegadores actuales.  Los ejemplo se enfocan en MVC porque el propio Angular tiene estructura como el modelo vista controlador, de hecho también hace uso de `controllers`.

La respuesta a tu pregunta es:  Si es posible.